# Changing exact scroll-position in a Listview

Tags: c#, wpf

Been searching around the net for the answer but I haven't found anything that does this:

I want to change the exact position in a WPF-list iew programmatically. Some way of saying

```
ListView.Scrollposition.Y = some value;
```

The only thing I can find is to change the value to a object within the Listview, not specific coordinates.
If anyone has some good articles or posts in this subject, I'd be very grateful!

Thanks.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37412462/refresh-scroll-position-of-wpf-comboxbox-on-itemsources-reload

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no way of doing that using the `ListView` element. Instead, you need to access its `ScrollViewer` and then you can use the [`ScrollViewer.ScrollToVerticalOffset` Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.scrollviewer.scrolltoverticaloffset%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to set the vertical position of the `ScrollViewer`. You'll also need to use the `ScrollViewer.VerticalOffset`, `ScrollViewer.VerticalOffset`, `ScrollViewer.ViewportHeight` and `ScrollViewer.ExtentHeight` properties to gauge where you are in the `ScrollViewer`.

From the [`ScrollViewer` Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.scrollviewer%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) page on MSDN:

> The area that includes all of the content of the ScrollViewer is the extent. The visible area of the content is the viewport.

Finally, how do you get the `ScrollViewer` from the `ListView`? I can't guarantee that this will work on a `ListView`, but it does on a `ListBox`. you can use the [`VisualTreeHelper.GetChild` Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.visualtreehelper.getchild%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to delve into the visual tree of the `ListView` and it should contain a `Border` and then the `ScrollViewer`, so you *should* be able to do something like this:

```
Border border = (Border)VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(YourListView, 0);
ScrollViewer scrollViewer = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(border, 0) as ScrollViewer;
if (scrollViewer != null)
{
    scrollViewer.ScrollToVerticalOffset(60.0);
}
```

If you *do* get an error with what the `GetChild` method returns, it'll be easy to adjust by debugging it. Just put a breakpoint there and see what each child type is and add another line with one of those elements... eventually, it should find the `ScrollViewer`. However, I think that that code should be fine.

Comment: Very in-depth answer, I'll have a look at the Scrollviewer class, almost knew it had to be it.. Thank you for this wonderful answer! :)

Answer (score 5):

If it's a `ListView` then first you'll need to find `ScrollViewer`:

```
private ScrollViewer FindScrollViewer(DependencyObject d)
{
   if (d is ScrollViewer)
      return d as ScrollViewer;

   for (int i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(d); i++)
   {
      var sw = FindScrollViewer(VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(d, i));
      if (sw != null) return sw;
   }
   return null;
}
```

and when you find it then you can [`ScrollToVerticalOffset`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.scrollviewer.scrolltoverticaloffset%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
var sw = FindScrollViewer(listView);
if (sw != null) sw.ScrollToVerticalOffset(x);
```

Comment: No problem. You did not mention why you want to scroll but you may also want to look into [`ListBox.ScrollIntoView`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.listbox.scrollintoview(v=vs.110).aspx) which allows you to bring specific item into view

Comment: Oh, sorry. I am trying to implement a kinetic-scrolling feature into my Listviews, so I really want a very precise scrolling instead of the item-by-item way (since that doesn't make sense for that purpose)

Comment: Thanks, @dkozl. How would I implement the above in an MVVM app?