# Refresh Scroll position of WPF ComboxBox on ItemSource's reload

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have a `ComboBox` which uses `ListBox` to show items. `ListBox`’s `ItemSource` is bound with a `CollectionViewSource`.

**Issue:** Once I open `ComboBox` and scroll through the items and leave it in middle or at bottom. Once I reopen `ComboBox`, even though I refresh or reload `ItemSource` (`CollectionViewSource`), the Scrollbar remains at the same place where I left it last time. I want it to be as default (at top) each and every time I reload `ItemSource`.

Is there is any way of doing this in XAML itself? Another thing, I cannot use Behavior or Attach property. I want any template or style for this.

Comment: Why can't you use Attached Behaviors / Attached Properties?

Answer (score 1):

In order for a Style on a ListBox to embody some behavior for the `<ScrollViewer>`, you would need to use an Attached Property / Attached Behavior to control the ScrollViewer's "grabber" position. This is because your collection is bound to your ListBox and notifying when it is updated needs to drive a behavior that isn't natively on the ListBox. It may be possible to reset the scroll position with a `<ControlTemplate>` for the `<ScrollViewer>` itself, but I imagine it would be difficult as it would likely involve manipulating Transforms / StoryBoards based on DataTriggering with your ItemsSource, but again that may cause a dependency on needing to use an Attached property, which for some reason you can't use...

If you simply want to get a result now, and you don't care about testability or re-usability, I would handle the `TargetUpdated` event in the code-behind. It's ultimately what the Attached Behavior would end up doing. On the other hand, if you do care about re-usability then you need to evaluate and challenge why you can't use an Attached Behavior (they are also testable, too); an Attached Behavior would be also easier than trying to edit a ControlTemplate.

Here is the code-behind approach:

**.xaml**:

```
<ListBox x:Name="myListBox" 
        ItemsSource="{Binding MyItemsSource, NotifyOnTargetUpdated=True}"
        TargetUpdated="ListBox_TargetUpdated"/>
```

**.xaml.cs**:

```
private void ListBox_TargetUpdated(object sender, DataTransferEventArgs e)
{
    if (myListBox.Items.Count > 0)
        myListBox.ScrollIntoView(myListBox.Items[0]);
}
```

**Edit:** On the flip-side, if you are using MVVM, you can do something like this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2292360/how-to-control-the-scroll-position-of-a-listbox-in-a-mvvm-wpf-app) suggests and set `IsSynchronizationWithCurrentItem="True"` and when you refresh your `ItemsSource`, simply set your `SelectedItem` to the first in the list and handle the SelectionChanged event in your vm.